# Faça um método static na classe principal que escreva na tela todos os números pares de 1 a 10000 que são palíndromos

Tags: java, array, loop

Este é o meu método:

```
public static void B()
{
    int vet[]=new int [100];
    int vet2[]=new int [vet.length/2];
    for(int i=0;i<=vet.length;i++)

    {
        vet[i]=i+1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<vet.length;i++)
    {
        int rest = vet[i]%2;
        if(rest==0)
        {
            vet2[i]=vet[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= vet2.length; i++) 
    {
        if(vet2[i]==(vet2[i-1])-i)
        {
            System.out.println(vet2[i]+"É PALINDROMO");
        }
    }
```

E esse é o erro que aparece:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100
>   at lista1.pkg05.Lista105.B(Lista105.java:59)
>   at lista1.pkg05.Lista105.main(Lista105.java:15)
> C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
> ```
>
> Java returned: 1

Comment: Esse código tem alguns erros, mas precisamos saber o objetivo dele para consertar, principalmente no último *loop* que certamente faz conta errada. Se for descobrir se um *array* é o inverso do outro, é óbvio que neste algoritmo não é.

Comment: Olá Fernando, será que poderia explicar melhor o que deseja? Quer somente a correção do código ou realmente o algoritmo para verificar se o número é palíndromo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O algoritmo tem um erro no `for` porque lê um número a mais. Você não pode comprar com `<=` ao tamanho porque a contagem começa no 0, tem que ser com `<`. Também funcionaria usar esta comparação subtraindo 1, mas isso gera um esforço computacional maior e não faz sentido usar assim.

O acesso para verificar se é palíndromo tem uma fórmula errada e causa problema também. Eu melhorei, mas acho que ainda não é o que deseja, porque é pra verificar se o *array* é palíndromo e não dizer sobre cada elemento, mas vai saber.

Um dos *arrays* não tem função alguma no algoritmo a não ser complicar.

Por este algoritmo nunca será palíndromo, mas eu espero que vá gerar o *array* com algum outro algoritmo que seja. Será que seria para verificar se os dígitos de cada número é palíndromo? Aí o algoritmo é outro. Mas já cai em outro problema.

Mantive apenas os 100 primeiros como foi feito na pergunta, talvez para ficar mais fácil testar, para ir até 10000, é só mudar o tamanho do *array*.

Dei uma organizada no código também.

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int vet[] = new int[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) if (i % 2 == 0) vet[i] = (i + 1) * 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) if (vet[i] == vet[vet.length - i - 1]) System.out.println(vet[i] + " É PALINDROMO");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bpuWMT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rwtxykzz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/Palindrome.java). Falta um dado, mas pelo menos o erro desaparece.

Comment: Não sei se faz sentido publicar um código tão cuidadoso, replicar em vários lugares, e que gera um output que não faz sentido nenhum. O objetivo do A.P. está bem claro no título da pergunta: ele quer imprimir os números que são Palíndromos.
Acho que uma abordagem legal seria sim, corrigir os limites do `for` e outros erros - mas aí questionar esse approach escolhido, que não vai levar a lugar nenhum. (Sim, eu vi que você falou que isso pode detectar se o "array é um palíndromo" - mas não é esse o objetivo - está no título)

Comment: O que está no título sequer está no escopo do site. Estamos aqui para resolver problemas específicos não realizar algoritmos inteiros para a pessoa. Me parece que a aceitação indica que resolveu o que ele queria. Eu gosto do meu fluxo de trabalho assim e prefiro manter um padrão.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, vou abordar isso de uma maneira mais legivel.

```
public class HelloWorld {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Palindromas();
   }
   public static void Palindromas()
   {

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();//Alocar Espaço para um SB

       for(int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {

         sb.append(i);//Adicionar o número no sb

         sb.reverse();//Inverter o número

         if(
            i % 2 == 0 // se  é par
            && // E
            Integer.parseInt(sb.toString()) == i //Ele ao contrário é igual a ele normal
            ){
             System.out.println(i);//Printa
         }

         sb.setLength(0);//Limpa o Buffer pra reutiliza-lo no proximo item do loop

      };
   }
}
```

Só fiz assim por que já tinha mais respostas, a minha é um workaround ;)

Comment: Na verdade, as outras respostas apontam o erro do código do autor, mas não imprimem os números que são palíndromos.

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta nessas duas linhas;

```
for(int i=0;i<=vet.length;i++)

for (int i = 0; i <= vet2.length; i++)
```

A propriedade length retorna o tamanho total de elementos no array, sendo assim ao utilizar para fazer a iteração de um array como o código acima, em um array de 10 posições ele ira percorre 11 vezes de 0 a 10 assim dando o erro ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException na decima primeira iteração, para resolver o problema segue o código abaixo.

```
for(int i=0;i<=vet.length -1;i++)

for (int i = 0; i <= vet2.length -1; i++)
```

Feito assim o código ira percorrer de 10 vezes de 0 a 9.